# Failed to load ...\x86\SNI.dll

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, dll

I am trying out Entity Framework (Core). I installed the packages from NuGet and wrote a very basic program to test things out. However, when I run it, I get `System.TypeInitializationException` and inside that, there is a `Win32Exception - Failed to load C:\\...Documents\\x86\\SNI.dll`.

The path where it's looking is wrong. The Dll is inside the project folder, but for some reason it is trying to load it from my documents folder. When I copy and paste the x86 folder from where it was installed to documents, the program works. However, I would be happier if it just worked the way it should, and loaded the Dll from where it is installed.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: did you reference SNL using NuGet?

Comment: I'm having the identical problem.   Any luck?   I've been working on it for three days.

Comment: I'm still not sure what was causing it, I think that the package installation was just confused by my folder structure (The project was in user/Documents/C#/project/[here]). Whenever I created a project in the folder C# and tried to install entityframework there, it didn't work because of the issue I described. But when I made a project in a different directory outside of documents and installed EF there, it worked fine.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. It tries to load the SNI.dll from D:\Company\Projects\x86\SNI.dll. But the project is located in D:\Company\Projects\C#\Live\pg_change_tool_new\DataAccess. It drives me mad... :-(

Answer (score 2):

For me it seems to be an issue with the string "C#" in the path, especially the "#" character.
I was facing the same issue. My path of the project was

> D:\Company\Projects\C#\Live\pg_change_tool_new\

...and it was trying to load the DLL from this path:

> D:\Company\Projects\x86\SNI.dll

After I cloned the project to a location without the string "C#" in the path name, it tried to load the DLL from the right location:

> D:\Company\Projects\pg_change_tool_new\PG_Change_Tool_UI\bin\Debug\x86\SNI.dll

...and it worked fine.

Comment: I've also had problems with the octothorpe in the path related to other issues.